# Getting TSA precheck with Global Entry

Tags: usa, airport-security, global-entry, tsa-precheck, trusted-traveler

I recently got a Global Entry card.
However on my last trip I was turned away from the pre check without an explanation. Why ? What do I have to do in addition to use pre check when I travel?
Thank you.

Comment: Which airport please?

Answer (score 5):

A Global Entry card doesn't itself get you into the TSA Precheck line. What's needed is a boarding pass from a [participating airline](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/map) that displays a precheck symbol; it looks [something like this](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2013/04/25/passengers-may-now-receive-notification-tsa-precheck-eligibility-boarding-passes).

To get that, you need to provide your known traveler number (KTN) to [an airline that participates in precheck at your airport](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/map). Your KTN is your [PASSID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-are-cbp-passid-and-known-traveler-number) that appears on the back of your Global Entry card. You'll need to [enter that number when you make airline reservations](https://travelguideltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/known-traveler-number-2-900x900.jpg). If you've already booked your tickets, there's usually a way to enter it by accessing your reservation online, or you can contact the airline for help. The airline's systems will send this number to TSA to confirm your Precheck eligibility and put the indicator on your boarding pass.

If it still doesn't show up, you can [ask the TSA to look into it](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2016/04/05/asktsa-travel-tips-over-140-characters-help-i-didnt-get-tsa-precheck-my-boarding-pass). You should ensure the name on your air reservation exactly matches the name on your Global Entry membership. Their [FAQ](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/faq) has additional information about how to use Precheck that may be of use.

Comment: If you have a frequent flyer account with a participating airline you may be able to add your KTN to your profile, automatically associating it with your reservations.

Comment: There are several airlines which do not participate in Precheck. Also, even if yours does and you provide your KTN, it is still possible that you will be randomly selected to go through regular screening, although this should be rare.

Comment: You can even get this addressed minutes before security: at the luggage-drop/check-in counter. Just tell them you TSA-PRE is missing, and they will take your known-traveller-number from the Global Entry card, enter it, and print you a new boarding pass. Unless you fly coconut- or cheapo-airlines that doesn't participate.